# Is past perfect a possible solution in this case

Tags: past-tense

Justin Stanfield broke into a garage . He **intended** to steal anything he could find of value so he could sell and buy some more drugs

I think past perfect could fit "had intended" meaning it was his plan and had decided
it before breaking into the garage .

https://www.liveworksheets.com/worksheets/en/English_as_a_Second_Language_(ESL)/Verb_tenses/Dumb_Criminals_-__A_narrative_tenses_practice_ct189fu

Comment: Actually, the fact that (fairly obviously) he must have formulated the intention ***before*** committing the break-in ***doesn't*** "justify" using Past Perfect. The only reason you would use ***had intended*** in your cited context is to strongly imply that he ***didn't actually*** steal anything of value (*although* he had intended something, the intended outcome didn't happen).

Comment: He intended to steal anything he could find of value so he could sell **it** and buy some more drugs

Comment: why it  did not justify the use of past perfect . You mean that when he broke out into the garage  he still intended to steal that is why past simple is better .

Comment: You could use the past perfect if he didn't steal anything - "He **had intended** to steal whatever he could find, **but** when the burglar alarm went off he ran away empty-handed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the "past perfect" there; but because the normal case would be that he was still intending that when he broke in, using it would imply that his intention changed when (or after) he broke in. If that's what you intend, fine. If it's not, then you risk confusing the reader.

Comment: Could I use past perfect if I change intended by decided?If so it would be "funny " because both verbs have the same meaning .

Comment: To my ear _he had decided_ carries much less of an implication that his plans changed. This is because _decide_ is a "punctual " verb - a decision is made at a particular point in time. If you say _he decided to steal_ that strongly suggests that the made that decision at the moment when he broke in, not previously. This is different from _intend_, which describes a state.

Comment: But the intention is also made at a particular point in time as a decision, I don't understand why intend describes a state

Comment: Because that is what the English word means. It does not refer to the moment of making a decision but to a mental state carried over a period. See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intention#English